# How to add a new target to GCC/Binutils

Tags: windows, gcc, cross-compiling, binutils

I'm trying to get the cross compiler for Windows RT beside Visual Studio. Unfortunately there is no MinGW-ARM so I have to do it by myself. I pretty much know what I want: PE32+, Thumb2 code always. Pretty sure that GCC can handle both so I thought it will be easy.

Apparently I'm wrong: I can't find a working target. Since I'd like to have MinGW, I chose "arm-w64-mingw32" as my target and configure of GAS told me it doesn't know what output format is. Also tried "arm-windows-pep", GCC didn't know what this is.

I took look at both configures, and I can hardly understand the logic in their code since there is not easy way to debug the shell script under Windows. Can somebody tells me the steps to add a new target?

Comment: back up, you want to compile for thumb2 with gcc on windows?  many solutions.  it is significantly, vastly, and other strong words, easier to find or build from scratch a gcc cross compiler for arm than it is to add a target.  if you have years to spare, then go ahead though, add an already existing target.

Comment: Just name some solutions. What I'm doing is exactly building a GCC cross compiler from scratch, and it doesn't work. Please just tell me the magic keyword for this already existing target.